# deleting all single nodes from neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have several nodes in my database that are not connected to any other nodes and I don't need them in the database. I have gone through [this guide](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/delete/) but it does not mention anything regarding deleting all single nodes. Is there any way I could delete all nodes that are not connected to any other nodes?

Example of single nodes in my database.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find any node labels and check if there is no connected nodes, then delete them

```
 MATCH (n)
 WHERE NOT((n)--())
 DELETE (n)
```

Comment: `WHERE NOT((n)--())` also works